# Why mkl_sparse_d_ev sparse eigensolver so slow?

Tags: c++, matlab, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl, eigenvector

I tried to use mkl_sparse_d_ev in intel-mkl to obtain the smallest eigenvector. However, I found that mkl seems very slow. The time for using matlab eigs for my test_FtF.txt file only 0.02s, but mkl needs 5s. Is anybody know about that?
Test files have been uploaded on https://github.com/qiqiSipangyiyou/mkl_test/tree/master. And here are my codes:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<vector>
#include "mkl.h"
#include "mkl_solvers_ee.h"
#include<chrono>

#define max(a, b) (a) < (b) ? (b): (a)

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    /* read Matrix A from file in COO format */
    //fstream FtF_file("/home/qicai/ap_build/mex_cmake/build-src-unknown-Default/mex/mexAdd/test.txt",std::ios::in);
    fstream FtF_file("/home/qicai/ap_build/mex_cmake/test_FtF.txt",std::ios::in);

    MKL_INT num_pts;//matrix size
    FtF_file>>num_pts;

    MKL_INT M = num_pts;               /* number of columns in matrix A */
    MKL_INT N = num_pts;               /* number of columns in matrix A */
    MKL_INT nnz = 0;             /* number of non-zeros in matrix */


    double tmp;
    cout<<num_pts<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<num_pts;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<num_pts;j++){
            FtF_file>>tmp;
            if(j<i)continue;
        //    cout<<"data:"<<tmp<<endl;
            if(abs(tmp)>1e-10){
                nnz++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"nonzeros:"<<nnz<<endl;
    FtF_file.clear();
    FtF_file.seekg(0);

    MKL_INT *ia=new MKL_INT[nnz];
    MKL_INT *ja=new MKL_INT[nnz];
    double *a=new double[nnz];
    MKL_INT id=0;
    FtF_file>>tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<num_pts;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<num_pts;++j){
            FtF_file>>tmp;
            if(j<i)continue;
            if(abs(tmp)>1e-10){
      //          cout<<"data:"<<tmp<<endl;

                ia[id]=i;
                ja[id]=j;
                a[id]=tmp;

                id++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<endl<<"ia:";
    for(int i=0;i<nnz;i++){
        cout<<ia[i]<<',';
    }
    cout<<endl<<"ja:";
    for(int i=0;i<nnz;i++){
        cout<<ja[i]<<',';
    }
    cout<<endl<<"a:";
    for(int i=0;i<nnz;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<',';
    }

    /* mkl_sparse_d_ev input parameters */
    char         which = 'S'; /* Which eigenvalues to calculate. ('L' - largest (algebraic) eigenvalues, 'S' - smallest (algebraic) eigenvalues) */
    MKL_INT      pm[128];     /* This array is used to pass various parameters to Extended Eigensolver Extensions routines. */
    MKL_INT      k0  = 1;     /* Desired number of max/min eigenvalues */

    /* mkl_sparse_d_ev output parameters */
    MKL_INT      k;           /* Number of eigenvalues found (might be less than k0). */
    double *E=new double[k0];
    double *X=new double[num_pts];
    double *res=new double[num_pts]; /* Residual */
    /* Local variables */
    MKL_INT      info;               /* Errors */
    MKL_INT      compute_vectors = 1;/* Flag to compute eigenvecors */
    MKL_INT      tol = 7;            /* Tolerance */

    /* Sparse BLAS IE variables */
    sparse_status_t status;
    sparse_matrix_t A = NULL; /* Handle containing sparse matrix in internal data structure */
    sparse_matrix_t B = NULL; /* Handle containing sparse matrix in internal data structure */

    struct matrix_descr descr; /* Structure specifying sparse matrix properties */

    /* Create handle for matrix A stored in CSR format */
    descr.type =SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_SYMMETRIC;
    descr.mode =SPARSE_FILL_MODE_UPPER;
    descr.diag =SPARSE_DIAG_NON_UNIT;

    status = mkl_sparse_d_create_coo ( &A, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO,N, N, nnz, ia, ja, a );
    mkl_sparse_convert_csr(A,SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE,&B);
    /* Step 2. Call mkl_sparse_ee_init to define default input values */
    mkl_sparse_ee_init(pm);

    pm[1] = tol; /* Set tolerance */
    pm[6] = compute_vectors;
    pm[2]=1;
    pm[8]=1;

    /* Step 3. Solve the standard Ax = ex eigenvalue problem. */
    auto start_time=chrono::steady_clock::now();
    info = mkl_sparse_d_ev(&which, pm, B, descr, k0, &k, E, X, res);
    auto end_time=chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dr_ms=std::chrono::duration<double>(end_time-start_time).count();
    cout<<"time cost for mkl_sparse_d_ev:"<<endl;
    cout << dr_ms <<endl;

    printf("mkl_sparse_d_ev output info %d \n",info);
    if ( info != 0 )
    {
        printf("Routine mkl_sparse_d_ev returns code of ERROR: %i", (int)info);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("*************************************************\n");
    printf("************** REPORT ***************************\n");
    printf("*************************************************\n");
    printf("#mode found/subspace %d %d \n", k, k0);
    printf("Index/Exact Eigenvalues/Estimated Eigenvalues/Residuals\n");

    mkl_sparse_destroy(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem size and version of mkl do you run? is that 32 or 64 bit code?

Comment: The test data is a 507x507 symmetric matrix and the version of mkl is provided by 26 Aug 2019. Codes build on 64 bit ubuntu system.

Comment: I also found the mkl very slow in my case, sir, do you still using mkl or using other alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your informative post.

i'm an early user of the FEAST algorithm, implementing it in my solution in 2013 using mkl_d_scsrev.

the results at that time looked good, but it was slow. i didn't need a solver that explicitly found the smallest eigenvalues, as my implementation relies on lord rayleigh's method to solve for the solution. here is a typical spectrum of eigenvalues:

```
 0.000000000113816
   0.000052601455356
   0.068554494321612
   0.087778615772763
   0.105495217707068
   0.145398755128103
   0.153359599671297
   0.166990929868295
   0.197868786741304
   0.213763001354604
   0.227400762098441
   0.291097321036999
   0.300763842400381
   0.305302888296127
   0.332127345676720
   0.350241982898846
   0.389572897678736
   0.395856794685699
   0.410521384132904
   0.431754775282753
   0.439616560992632
   0.477365205294176
   0.490147737858001
   0.529157345517078
   0.537043303855166
   0.555797275585461
   0.559068290525491
   0.584834420878695
   0.593687156341006
   0.608693506870185
   0.640229256337295
   0.661795512043067
   0.676367783421366
   0.686068898197173
   0.713067918770893
   0.729422050221797
   0.745196065198519
   0.751154791383512
   0.761933289037113
   0.777860229731929
   0.784891531764446
   0.806535649179089
   0.833696598794123
   0.851297121061303
   0.855422217846293
   0.860794248786557
   0.865141767516436
   0.901483081144584
   0.905579480589993
   0.913602071326502
   0.925379134193968
   0.942753309326689
   0.953897009231039
   0.979751986135300
   1.011019504756326
   1.016122749075099
   1.030126864762692
   1.031564165601732
   1.053214415037729
   1.071158599300634
   1.077060789308419
   1.097263289685497
   1.103380073458037
   1.111674904566733
   1.120015742700657
   1.139368728838865
   1.145162957746346
   1.161511561737053
   1.179308620139401
   1.195789171646983
   1.207110509211700
   1.230549104692518
   1.240878928528908
   1.250963040068006
   1.266711531681346
   1.279171190128492
   1.287090567153517
   1.305683286771664
   1.319327693109748
   1.330050064103239
   1.334948506703003
   1.360268435916191
   1.364678416331985
   1.376975215445382
   1.398922661960245
   1.401811425721273
   1.415977204274010
   1.432371319880490
   1.438918769913687
   1.447372902751351
   1.450444923403454
   1.454764871071615
   1.474418736215698
   1.491825652640958
   1.499335384244923
   1.508176502782256
   1.517346123252436
   1.533887183082747
   1.556214985742326
   1.558403670259501
   1.570744410070948
   1.584636427261357
   1.587627459101911
   1.590915887411250
   1.612816119762401
   1.629319504265405
   1.632101560419300
   1.640818069423384
   1.652009133732152
   1.664440418680059
   1.671294761655573
   1.677415022494883
   1.687908846894166
   1.702919268005902
   1.713223391443884
   1.733354506326609
   1.737093913144649
   1.751925735458567
   1.756431973298564
   1.762142509981560
   1.779693162731277
   1.787008677655163
   1.800588591489155
   1.810024069849310
   1.828373955163949
   1.833689264411773
   1.843327809187262
   1.845139266943621
   1.861889517821866
   1.879394388480029
   1.888059848317457
   1.908489307237925
   1.914784507326902
   1.928039186874031
   1.934265621669847
   1.937520648445936
```

look up work by dr killian weinberger if you have questions on my use case.

anyways coming back to why i'm posting: intel's extremal eigenvalue solver sucks. badly.

scsrev is good but, like i said, it's slow because of the iterations and convergence criteria. intel is free to claim mkl_sparse_d_ev is merely a wrapper, but whatever it's doing is terrible. the eigenvectors i'm getting back are often low-quality and unnecessarily in the thousandths decimal place!:

```
Computing K (26) nearest neighbours for 55356 voxels...
I.   Calculating reconstruction weights...
II.  Computing Embedding using reconstruction weights...
III. Computing the d-dimensional manifolds (Eigensolver)...
retval3 is 0
eig[0] is -0.000000, values are:0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 
eig[1] is 0.000000, values are:0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 0.000085 
eig[2] is 0.047576, values are:0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 
eig[3] is 0.092780, values are:0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 
eig[4] is 0.121316, values are:0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 0.000094 
eig[5] is 0.182291, values are:0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 0.000093 
eig[6] is 0.206669, values are:0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 0.000089 
eig[7] is 0.216510, values are:0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 0.000073 
eig[8] is 0.249239, values are:0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 0.000070 
...
eig[12] is 0.402550, values are:0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 0.000071 
eig[13] is 0.444249, values are:0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 0.000024 
eig[14] is 0.466680, values are:0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 0.000095 
eig[15] is 0.488172, values are:0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 
eig[16] is 0.514233, values are:0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 0.000065 
eig[17] is 0.552217, values are:0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 0.000061 
eig[18] is 0.563018, values are:0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 0.000058 
eig[19] is 0.615128, values are:0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 0.000026 
eig[20] is 0.652937, values are:-0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 -0.000041 
eig[21] is 0.672198, values are:0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 0.000105 
eig[22] is 0.685197, values are:-0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 -0.000180 
eig[23] is 0.694570, values are:-0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 -0.000222 
eig[24] is 0.765057, values are:0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 0.000068 
eig[25] is 0.814175, values are:0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 0.000046 
eig[26] is 0.879965, values are:0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 
eig[27] is 0.896827, values are:0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 0.000064 
...
eig[975] is 15.021939, values are:0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 
eig[976] is 15.035126, values are:0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974 0.000974
```

this is going to be a bigger headache thank i thought. how can intel expect me to deploy MKL if they don't even have this part handled?
unitary eigenvector for a non-zero eigenvalue? what a damn joke!

MATLAB is hands down the best for solving!